# How does Java capture type variables in a generic method of a generic interface?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

The file GenericInterface.java:

```
import java.lang.Comparable;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class GenericInterface {
}

interface Comparator<T> {
  int compare(T o1, T o2);

  static <T, U extends Comparable<?>> //comment out this line
  //static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> //and uncomment this line to pass compiling
  Comparator<T> Comparing(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper) {
    return new Comparator<T>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        return mapper.apply(o1).compareTo(mapper.apply(o2));
      }
    };
  }

  //...
}
```

Then compile it with JDK 1.8 by `javac GenericInterface.java -Xdiags:verbose`, resulting the following error:

```
GenericInterface.java:16: error: method compareTo in interface 
Comparable<T#2> cannot be applied to given types;
        return mapper.apply(o1).compareTo(mapper.apply(o2));
                               ^
  required: CAP#1
  found: CAP#2
  reason: argument mismatch; U cannot be converted to CAP#1
  where U,T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    U extends Comparable<?> declared in method <T#1,U>Comparing(Function<? super T#1,? extends U>)
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1,U>Comparing(Function<? super T#1,? extends U>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in interface Comparable
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
    CAP#2 extends U from capture of ? extends U
1 error
```

I can pass compiling by changing this line

```
static <T, U extends Comparable<?>>
```

to this

```
static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>>
```

But I don't know why:

```
CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
CAP#2 extends U from capture of ? extends U
```

Shouldn't CAP#1 and CAP#2 be `U extends Comparable<?>`? Could anyone tell me how Java captures type variables in a generic method of a generic interface like the one above?

Answer (score 1):

Where you have `U extends Comparable<?>` the `compareTo` function will be `int compareTo(? o)`. `?` is wild so the only valid argument is `null`.

Conversely, where you have `U extends Comparable<? super U>` you will have `int compareTo(? super U o)`, which will take any `U`.

For instance if I was to declare

```
class Thing extends Comparable<String> {
    int compareTo(String o) { return 0; }
}
```

then call

```
Comparator.<Date,Thing>Comparing(myFunc)
```

We have a problem `Thing.compareTo(String)` is called with a `Thing` argument.

(Made up notation, obviously.)

Comment: Why "? is wild so the only valid argument is null", since "the compareTo function will be int compareTo(? o)"? Why not the valid argument being "Object"?

Comment: `?` could be anything. It isn't defined locally. If in the object supplied it were a `String` say (as in my example) and supplied a `Thing` that couldn't be right.